# How to sort case classes with Option[String] in alphabetical order ignoring None's?

Tags: scala

Given a `List[Foo]` where `Foo` is defined as:

```
case class Foo(bar: Option[String])
```

what's the best way for me to find the `Foo` with the first `bar` in alphabetical order?

For example, if I had:

```
val l = List(Foo(None), Foo(Some("xyz")), Foo(Some("abc")))
```

I would like to return `Foo(Some("abc"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   list.filter(_.bar.isDefined) match {
      case Nil => Foo(None)
      case l => l.minBy(_.bar)
   }
```

Or, if there will always be at least one non-empty option, then just `list.filter(_.bar.isDefined).minBy(_.bar)`

This is (marginally) better than sorting, because it's linear, and does not require allocating data structures.

One more possibility, which is even (a tiny bit) more efficient (but slightly more involved) is

```
list.reduceOption { 
    case (Foo(None), x) => x
    case (x, Foo(None)) => x
    case (Foo(Some(x)), Foo(Some(y))) => if ( x < y ) Foo(Some(x)) else Foo(Some(y))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sortBy`, then `collectFirst` to pattern match the first element that doesn't contain `None`:

```
l.sortBy(_.bar).collectFirst { case x @ Foo(Some(_)) => x }
```

Note that this will return `Option[Foo]`, in case all of the elements of the list contain `None`, then the above code will return `None`. Otherwise `Some(first matching element)`.

If you're super confident that the list will always contain a non-empty `Option`, then use `get` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use foldLeft. It will work faster as there is no need to sort list:

```
import Ordering.Implicits._

val res = l.foldLeft(Foo(None))((res, foo) =>
  if (res.bar.isEmpty) foo
  else if (foo.bar.isEmpty) res
  else if (res.bar < foo.bar) res
  else foo)

println(res) // Foo(Some(abc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter list before sorting.

```
l.filter {_ match {
    case Foo(None) => false
    case _ => true
  }
}.minBy(_.bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most functional approach I see here so far. It also doesn't need to sort anything:

```
 case class Foo(bar: Option[String])
 val l = List(Foo(None), Foo(Some("xyz")), Foo(Some("abc")))

  val foo = l.foldLeft(Foo(None)) {
    (acc, elem) => (for {
      elemB  <- elem.bar
      accB <- acc.bar
      smaller = if( elemB <  accB) elem else acc
    } yield smaller)
      .getOrElse(elem)
  }

  System.out.println(foo.bar)
```